# iPhone can't get selectedrow index

Tags: iphone, ios4

I just want to simply save the selected index as integer but the code below returns a weird value and can get the index as an integer, what is wrong here?

```
NSInteger *selectedRow;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

self.selectedRow=(NSInteger *)indexPath.row;
}
```

Comment: Make `selectedRow` a `NSInteger`, not `NSInteger *`, and remove the cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `selectedRow` is an `NSInteger`, which is not an object type, just a typedef of an int (long?) primative. Thus, you don't want a pointer to an `NSInteger`, you should remove your cast `(NSInteger*)` and just leave:

```
self.selectedRow= indexPath.row;
```

Comment: and how can I convert in into a string? NSString *val=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",selectedRow]; did not work

Comment: did you try with self.selectedRow? What is the property declaration of selectedRow?

Answer (score 1):

`NSInteger` is not an object. You are casting it in the wrong way. Just try `self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;`.